# Having issues looping through variants for Commerce 2 Products using Element API

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-elementapi, plugin-craftcommerce2

I'm currently able to return the first variant using the following:

```
<?php
use craft\commerce\elements\Product;
use craft\helpers\UrlHelper;

return [
  'endpoints' => [
    'products.json' => function () {
      return [
        'elementType' => Product::class,
        'paginate' => false,
        'pretty' => true,
        'criteria' => [
          // 'id' => $productId,
        ],
        'transformer' => function (Product $product) {
          foreach ( $product->getVariants() as $variant ) {
            $variants = [
              'type'          => $product->type->name,
              'title'         => $variant->title,
              'sku'           => $variant->sku,
              'price'         => $variant->price,
              'stock'         => $variant->stock,
              'intro'         => $variant->intro,
              'purchasableId' => (int) $variant->purchasableId,
              'status'        => $variant->status,
              'url'           => $variant->url,
              // 'productPhoto'  => $variant->productPhoto
            ];
          }

          return $variants;
        }
      ];
    }
  ]
]
?>
```

Which returns:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      type: "Shakes",
      title: "3 Month Supply",
      sku: "mvn-a03m",
      price: "100.0000",
      stock: "0",
      intro: "<p>This is another 3M variant</p>",
      purchasableId: 37,
      status: "enabled",
      url: "https://testing.kamicrafted.com/shop/products/mavenshake?variant=37"
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue is that I currently have 3 variants set for this product yet the json response only shows the last variant within the set.

I'm completely stumped at this point and was hoping someone had a similar experience with a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the whole `$variants` variable to last item in the array instead of creating the `$variants` array variable and pushing items into it. Should be this:

```
'transformer' => function (Product $product) {
          $variants = [];

          foreach ( $product->getVariants() as $variant ) {
            $variants[] = [
              'type'          => $product->type->name,
              'title'         => $variant->title,
              'sku'           => $variant->sku,
              'price'         => $variant->price,
              'stock'         => $variant->stock,
              'intro'         => $variant->intro,
              'purchasableId' => (int) $variant->purchasableId,
              'status'        => $variant->status,
              'url'           => $variant->url,
              // 'productPhoto'  => $variant->productPhoto
            ];
          }

          return $variants;
        }
```

Comment: thank you so much! i'm stumbling my way through element API so your help is much appreciated. i can see what i was doing wrong now :)